# Find maximum sized antichains in this poset

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I think I might be misunderstanding the concept of maximum antichains. Based on the question in my textbook, it seems as if there are multiple maximum antichains for this poset. Why is the maximum antichain not just the subset I circled in red? Each element in this subset seems incomparable to me.

[image]

Comment: Every dot in the upper part is comparable with every dot in the lower part.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. So even though the single middle dot is between them and they aren't directly connected they are still comparable?

Comment: yes, by transitivity.

Comment: Okay. So The bottom row of dots would still be part of the anti chain, but instead of the top row, you would add the pairs of two dots on either side of the middle dot for a total size of 9?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements at the bottom are actually comparable to the elements at the top, simply because of transitivity, as was explained in the comments.

Now, if you are finding an antichain from a diagram, you need a set of points like this : *there's no path from one point to the other, via the joining lines, which either is constantly going down or constantly coming up*. I want you to prove this from the definition of a poset, and the way the diagram is drawn.

From this, one clearly gets that the largest anti chain in this poset is of size $9$. You seem to have found it in a comment above.